# Can a parent's class method call an abstract method which will be implemented in a child class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, abstract

If I have a parent class with two methods:

```py
class Parent():
    @abstractmethod
    @staticmethod
    def functionA():
       pass
    
    def functionB():
       return __class__.functionA() + 1
```

And I implement a child class:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def functionA(): # this function is different for each kind of child
        return 3
```

In the end, the purpose of the child classes would be to call `functionB()` only.
Does it work? Of course, I could place `functionB()` into the child class and make it work, but because `functionB()` is the same for every kind of child class, I wouldn't want to write repeated code for each class?

Also, is my use of `__class__` appropriate here?

Comment: Why don't you define `functionB` as a `@classmethod` and return different instances of parent class?

Answer (score 4):

First, `functionB` itself should be a class method.

```
@classmethod
def functionB(cls):
    return cls.functionA() + 1
```

Second, you still have to decorate `functionA` as a static method in each child class; otherwise, you are replacing the inherited static method with an instance method.

```
class Child(Parent):

    @staticmethod
    def functionA():
        return 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Parent(ABC):
    @staticmethod # not needed, but is documentation
    @abstractmethod
    def a(): pass

    @classmethod
    def b(cls): return cls.a() + 1

class Child(Parent):
    @staticmethod
    def a(): return 3
```

We can test it:

```
>>> c = Child()
>>> c.b()
4
```

Noteworthy things:

- We need to use the `ABC` base class (or the `ABCMeta` metaclass) in order to have access to the `abstractmethod` decorator, as explained in the `abc` module documentation.
- `__class__` is not a keyword; it is an *attribute of objects*. We cannot just do things like `__class__.a()` because there is nothing to get the `__class__` *from*. We *could* address this using the `self` parameter of an ordinary method, but what we are really trying to do here is to get behaviour that *doesn't require an instance, yet depends on which derived class we are using*. And that is what `classmethod` is for, and why there are separate `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators.

When you use `classmethod`, the class will be passed as a parameter, like how the instance is passed when you use a normal method. By convention, we name it `cls`. For more information about `classmethod`, please see [this excellent talk by Raymond Hettinger (on the Python dev team)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg).

- Our implementations of the abstract method must also be decorated in the child classes, because they are still not ordinary methods - so Python needs to know not to pass an instance.
- The `staticmethod` decoration on the abstract method needs to be *listed first*, before the `abstractmethod` decoration, for technical reasons. It effectively does nothing here; the `abstractmethod` would already behave like a `staticmethod` when we call e.g. `Parent.a()` (no instance; we can't create one anyway, since it's an abstract class).
- We could also use `classmethod` instead of `staticmethod` for the `a` methods. This would allow children of `Child` to inherit the `Child` behaviour without explicitly writing their own `a` implementations. In this case, we would want an explicit `classmethod` decoration on the base abstract method, rather than `staticmethod`; and of course we would need to add `cls` parameters to each `a` implementation.

Comment: Thank you, seems like using `classmethod` is the way to go here.